# App will be available for download on customer website in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Is this Possible in iOS:

1.App will be available for download on customer website. Option to download will be given

2.Anyone can download app but the app will not be available on App Store

3.It should be ad-hoc or enterprise program or something that will make that happen

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: AFAIK that is only possible if you jailbreak your devices.

Comment: No i want to do it for all user not only Jailbreak user .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found some useful document to solve this problem :

FOA: The Answer is **YES** . We can grab above functionality .

With the Help of **Enterprise based App** (In-House) we can do this .

Some of the Useful Doc reference here :

[iOS Enterprise Deployment Overview](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Enterprise_Deployment_Overview.pdf)

[iOS Deployment Reference](https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apd5b9e6434f)

Answer (score 4):

If you choose Enterprise App, it can be put on customer website and can be downloaded/installed without jailbreaking.

You can find details for it here developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works. And trust me it works. The app can be distributed to people, but you shouldn't sell it to people without AppStore.

Comment: Can you please provide me any link to do this . Actually most of the people saying that  It is not possible so Please if you can .

Comment: @iThink You can find details for it here https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/how-it-works/.  And trust me it works. The app can be distributed to people, but you shouldn't sell it to people without AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want possible and you can do this easily with out any problem.

1. In your Project build settings go to Code Signing and set the
   Distribution provisioning profile, note that it must be distribution
   profile not an Adhoc profile.
2. Now from IOS simulators select the first option "IOS Device". It is not
   necessary that your actual Iphone is also connected to your laptop.
3. Now go to your projects info.plist file and in that file their is a
   Key named as "Application requires iPhone env" set that key's value to 'YES'.
4. Now go to Product -> Archive.
5. Once archive is completed then without validating just Export your .ipa file to  your desktop.
6. Now you can upload that .ipa file to any site and make a plist for that .ipa file.
7. Now upload that plist file on any site and then use the URL of
   that plist file to download and install your ipa on **any** iphone
   device.
8. To download and install your app, just hit the URL of your plist in
   iphone's Safari browser and that will ask your permission to install
   the app. Thats it , hope it helps.